# Protecting text and links from being taken over

Tags: javascript

We create content with preset links to merchants. Recently it appears that some of the keywords (like a product name) is being highlighted by some kind of javascript redirecting to other merchants.  The javascript in this case in skimlinks, but there are others (viglinks, infolinks etc).

Are there any ways to protect content by encasing it in some code so other javascripts on the page don't hijack the text or links?

thanks

Comment: you should be looking to fix the root of the problem not just put bandaids on it. The root of the problem is that you have malicious script being injected on your page that needs to be removed. This is most often caused by not properly validating/sanitizing user input from a form. "They" are already in your door, so no, there is no way to fix this. They can simply circumvent whatever js "encasing" you do - or just start making their own links

Comment: and you'd better do it quick if you care about search engines not blacklisting your site

Comment: also, are you sure this is actually being done ON your site, and not from YOUR computer having malware on it?